# Checking if element is in a Set

Tags: apex, compile-error

I wrote a method last night that creates a new custom object record that is related to an Account and a User. it works great however, it breaks when there is an already existing record for a user. After research I think I need a set to compare if the user value already exists then not run the logic.

I can't get the syntax right to compile and see if it works. Example code:

```
public static void createNPDAccountTeam(Map<Id, Id> accOwner)
{
    List<NPD_Account_Team__c> npdAccTeamToInsert = new List<NPD_Account_Team__c>();
    Set<NPD_Account_Team__c> existingAccTeam = new Set<NPD_Account_Team__c>();
    existingAccTeam.addAll([SELECT Id, User__c, Account__c FROM NPD_Account_Team__c WHERE Account__c IN: accOwner.keySet()]);

    for(Id accId : accOwner.keySet())
    {
        if(!existingAccTeam.contains(accId.User__c)
        {
            npdAccTeamToInsert.add(new NPD_Account_Team__c(
                Account__c = accId,
                User__c = accOwner.get(accId),
                Role__c = 'Custom',
                Team_Member_Status__c = 'Active'
                ));
        }
    }
    insert npdAccTeamToInsert;
}
```

I get the error on line 10:

> Unexpected token '{'

What am I doing wrong? I know that it does not need a ; at the end of the if line but I am not sure why it will not save.

Comment: Missing parentheses after the `contains` method call.. Also, `accId` is an Id so `accId.User__c` is likely to throw an error once you fix that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please close the if condition with extra parens.

```
if(!existingAccTeam.contains(accId.User__c))
{

}
```

Comment: Damn, I knew it had to be something simple like that. I get a different error now though. Should that be a new question?

Comment: yes, you can put a new question